# Parsing XML in C# like JavaScript

Tags: c#, xml, json, parsing

I know everyone says the best way to parse XML in C# is to use the XmlDocument class and do something like:

```
XmlNodeList list = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('tag');
```

However, I **LOVE** the way JavaScript encapsulates its XML and JSON, where every level of encapsulation within the XML or JSON document can be accessed using '.' i.e.:

test.xml

```
<item>
 <title>Title</title>
 <desc>
    <meta>MetaData</meta>
    <content>Ipsum Lorem</content>
 </desc>
 <date>1/1/2013</date>
</item>
```

In javasript I could parse this XML file and assign it to an object, var obj. I could then do something like:

```
obj.item[0].title ( 'Title' )
obj.item[0].desc.meta ('MetaData')
```

Is there any C# library that can parse the XML into something like this or do I have to do it the other way?

Comment: There isn't such a library because C# is compiled and JS is interpreted. You could create classes into which you could deserialize your XML if it's static. There's a tool to generate such classes from XML. Or you can use XDocument - a bit more verbose than custom class but better than XmlDocument

Comment: I know that "everybody" doesn't say use XmlDocument. I personally say use `XDocument` and LINQ to XML.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly the same, but this kind of approach (reading XML into a dynamic object) is similar in spirit:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/436406/Power-of-Dynamic-Reading-XML-and-CSV-files-made-ea

Comment: this looks pretty damn close. Thanks I will give it a try

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to take a look at a tool that should have been included with your visual studio installation:  xsd.exe.  Specifically take a look at the /classes switch.  It isn't quite what you are looking for, but it will yield a similar syntax.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to branch into the dynamic aspects of C# and `ExpandoObject`, there is a **very** clever library by @amazedsaint that seems like what you're after:

- Introductory blog post: [Introducing ElasticObject implemented using .NET 4.0 dynamic features - An easier way to work with XML in CSharp, A Smarter Cousin of ExpandoObject](http://www.amazedsaint.com/2010/02/introducing-elasticobject-for-net-40.html)
- Source code: [ElasticObject on CodePlex](http://elasticobject.codeplex.com/)
- Codeproject article: [Adventures with C# 4.0 dynamic - ExpandoObject, ElasticObject, and a Twitter client in 10 minutes](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/62839/Adventures-with-C-4-0-dynamic-ExpandoObject-Elasti)

Example:

```
dynamic item = new ElasticObject("item");
item.Title = "Title";
item.Desc = new { Meta = "Metadata", Content="Lorem Ipsum" };
XElement asXml = item > FormatType.Xml;

// and from xml:
dynamic itemFromXml = asXml.ToElastic();
```